# Second rewrite does never execute

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:user_profile)?\?user_id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user_profile?user_id=$1 [L]
```

which correctly lets me use domain/username as an url.

But when I add one more rewrite rule similar to that, the second one does not like the one above did.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:group)?\?group_id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^group/([^/]+)/?$ /group?group_id=$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me to rewite the second one which return like this domain/group/groupname while keeping the first one working like domain/username.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The first problem is that you want to keep the `group/` prefix when you redirect the request.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:group)?\?group_id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /group/%1? [L,R]
```

The second problem is that after the first rewrite pass, you rewrite `/group/groupname` to `/group?group_id=groupname`. This will make `/group` match against the username rule. You want to prevent this prefix from matching:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/group
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /user_profile?user_id=$1 [L]
```